# What's the meaning and part of speech of 两种 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

> 喝彩有正彩，倒彩两种。

It's a sentence from an article about 喝彩. What's this "两种" (two types) semantically and grammatically? I understand it (probably wrong) as: cheering has a positive shade, booing two types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 喝彩有正彩，倒彩两种。

It means: *there are two types of cheering, (namely) positive cheering and negative cheering(booing)*.

The sentence can be rephrased as 喝彩有两种(形式)，正彩，倒彩。

Comment: OK, your answer is more like what I was looking for. But the original order is strange for me. Can I use this order in sentences like example below?
------------
1. 我做两个工作，老师，警察 ---> 我做老师，警察两个工作
--------------
2. 我喜欢两种水果，苹果，芒果 ---> 我喜欢苹果，芒果两种水果

Comment: @musialmi Yes，except  for the first one.  The measure word for 工作 is 份，so we can say 我做两份工作，老师和警察。

Answer (score 0):

I say 喝采 for real cheers and 倒喝采 for booing others.

兩種 means two kinds.

Answer (score 0):

According to 百度：

喝彩，是汉语词汇，汉语拼音为hè cǎi 。
过去指的是是赌博掷骰子，呼喝作势，希望中彩。
后用以大声叫好。
如：宋 张任国 《柳梢青》词：“挂起招牌。一声喝采，旧店新开。”

and for 倒彩：

指观众在看演出或其他的表演时，故意发出不满的怪叫声。
老舍 《四世同堂》五八：“她不能随便得罪人，以至招出个倒彩来。” 张天翼 《谭九先生的工作》：“演戏呢，也一定会弄得一蹋糊涂，台底下的人都喝着倒彩，一个个把茶壶茶杯摔上台去。”

正彩：doesn't seem to be a word, but can be taken to mean the opposite of 倒彩 here.

All in all I think we have:

喝彩有正彩，倒彩两种。
There are two ways （两种） of showing your opinion: cheers and jeers.